# AIX shell execution permission denied even with sudo

Tags: shell, unix, permissions, sh, aix

I'm trying to execute a shell script on a AIX server, using bash, where I have speruser rights and I'm still getting this error. Is there a way to bypass the "permission denied" problem?

```
/files/data/ant/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant: 

/files/data/java/jre17/bin/java: 

0403-006 Execute permission denied.
```

chmod on the entire folder (including the script) is set to 777.
Would be nice to understand also why I'm getting this error, although I have superuser rights.

PS: Even went and used `sudo -su` before and no success.

Comment: could you run your script with sudo command.  eg user@host:/ sudo ./yourScript

Comment: yes, i ran the script with sudo and still got an error

Comment: could you provide permisions ; ls -lart /files/data/java/jre17/bin/java    and    ls -lart /files/data/ant/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant outputs

Comment: and ls -lart yourscriptpath

Comment: everything in the data folder has 777 permissions, including the script

Comment: could you try  debug script using ; bash -x yourScript, what is result

Comment: You also need execute permission on all the directories in the path.

Comment: @OP: It is not clear what is the command  you tried. If you want to see what's happening, run it this way: `bash -xv myscriptname.sh`

Comment: I tried to execute a shellscript from one folder inside the data folder, that script would call for and and java to follow up an installation. I have 777 rights over those folders and files and running as super user didn't help

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.